# Rails saving a pdf to Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, amazon-s3

I have a Rails 3.2 app that uses gem 'wicked_pdf', and gem 'combine_pdf'.
They both work and I can create PDFs which get emailed.

But, I have run into a situation where the email would be too big.

So, I'm trying to save the created pdf to Amazon S3.  The app already has the gem 'aws-sdk'.

This is my code:

```
  def self.saveallpdf
    @costprojects = Costproject.where("client_id = 2")
    pdf = CombinePDF.new
    @costprojects.each do |costproject|
      @costproject = costproject
      controller = CostprojectsController.new
      controller.instance_variable_set(:"@costproject", @costproject)
      pdf2 = controller.render_to_string(pdf: "Captital Projects.pdf",
                                         template: "costprojects/viewproject",
                                         encoding: "UTF-8")
      pdf << CombinePDF.parse(pdf2)
    end
    @s3 = AWS::S3.new
    @bucket = @s3.buckets['ndeavor3-pdf']
    @obj = @bucket.objects['filename'].write(pdf, acl: :public_read)
  end
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
:data must be provided as a String, Pathname, File, or an object that responds to #read and #eof?
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/aws-sdk-1.8.3.1/lib/aws/s3/data_options.rb:125:in `validate_data!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/aws-sdk-1.8.3.1/lib/aws/s3/data_options.rb:32:in `compute_write_options'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/aws-sdk-1.8.3.1/lib/aws/s3/s3_object.rb:594:in `write'
/app/app/models/costproject.rb:167:in `saveallpdf
```

'

I guess was-sdk doesn't like the "pdf" as the file??

PS - I can email the "pdf" - if it was smaller in size.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point in time:

```
@obj = @bucket.objects['filename'].write(pdf, acl: :public_read)
```

`pdf` is a `CombinePDF` object and not a `File`, `String`, or `Pathname`

`pdf.to_s` might work, or you will have to create a new file from the `CombinePDF` object

```
File.new(CombinePDF) # pseduo code only
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. pdf.to_s didn't work.  Not sure how to code the File.new line - I'll try researching it.

Comment: I got it to work using     file = Tempfile.new('costprojects.pdf')